# Angular project did not work after ng build

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

My first attempt on Angularjs 2, after an `ng build`, it compiled to the dist folder but the index.html in the folder has all the scripts having missing reference despite it all exist in the same folder.
Has anyone encountered this before? What do you suggest?
Attached herewith is the snapshot of the error in chrome.[image]

Comment: Post the error you're getting

Comment: When you run it using "ng serve" does it work? From your description, it's not clear what problem you are facing.

Comment: `ng serve` works fine. I have actually done some cool stuff on it. Since JS on default does not support .ts extension, I need to build to utilize in my server side application.

Comment: @raven, attached is the error message

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are opening index.html just from the file system using the file:// protocol. That doesn't work, because the application is built with  tag, which says, that all relative paths should be prefixed by "/". With the file protocol, it means in the root of your file system.

You can build the application specifying a different base path:

```
ng build --base-href=/path/to/your/application/dist/
```

You can also consider deploying it to a web server which can map all paths to your index.html (e.g. Apache + mod_rewrite), so when you hit the reload button in your browser, the application will load not matter what route.

Comment: How does this work using XAMP? Do I need to specify the path at `ng build`?

Comment: If you want to deploy somewhere else than the website root, you need to specify the base-href path. But if you just want to develop your application at localhost, it's better to use node.js by running "ng serve" instead of "ng build". Then you have your application available at localhost:4200